# Change View in Fragment if SQLite it is null or has a record

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to change the view in one Fragment which I have called history.
I want if the DB SQLite has record there show me the listview but if there is empty show me another view.
If the DB has record the view calls the history_item as layout and historyName to show TextView
I want if the DB has no record call the fragment_history where there is LinearLayout with ImageView and TextView.

history_item.XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_home"
    android:id="@+id/historyLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@id/ivHistory" style="@style/ivHistory" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/historyName" android:layout_height="38dp" style="@style/TextViewQuery"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgViewSetQuery" style="@style/ImageViewSetQuery" />
    <TextView android:textSize="@dimen/search_font" android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/btnDeleteHistory" android:background="@color/red" android:paddingLeft="5.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="5.0dip" android:visibility="gone" android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="@string/Delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentHistory.class

```
public class FragmentHistory extends Fragment {
    View paramView;
   public  TextView textView, showDeleteButton, noSearch;
    LinearLayout test;
    public ImageView showHistoryQuery;

    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

    private ListView mListView;
    private LinearLayout noQueries;
    public FragmentHistory() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history, container, false);
        textView = paramView.findViewById(R.id.historyName);
        noSearch = paramView.findViewById(R.id.tvHistoryPage);
        mListView = paramView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        noQueries = paramView.findViewById(R.id.linLayoutEmptyList);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        populateListView();
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setFragmentRefreshListener(new MainActivity.FragmentRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(FragmentHistory.this).attach(FragmentHistory.this).commit();
            }
        });


        return paramView;
    }

    private void populateListView() {


        //get the data and append to a list
        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            listData.add(data.getString(1));
        }
            ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.history_item, R.id.historyName, listData);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);


     mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             String name = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

             Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getItemID(name); //get the id associated with that name
             int itemID = -1;
             while(data.moveToNext()){
                 itemID = data.getInt(0);
             }
             if(itemID > -1){
                 Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivitySearchEngine.class);
                 editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",itemID);
                 editScreenIntent.putExtra("name",name);
                 startActivity(editScreenIntent);
             }

         }
     });

        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String name = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getItemID(name); //get the id associated with that name
                int  itemID = -1;

                while(data.moveToNext()){
                    itemID = data.getInt(0);
                }
                if(itemID > -1){
                    showDeleteButton = view.findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteHistory);
                    showHistoryQuery =  view.findViewById(R.id.imgViewSetQuery);
                    showDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    showHistoryQuery.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    final int finalItemID = itemID;
                    final String finalName = name;

                    showDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mDatabaseHelper.deleteName(finalItemID, finalName);
                            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft.detach(FragmentHistory.this).attach(FragmentHistory.this).commit();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }


}
```

fragment_history.XML

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvHistory" android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />
    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linLayoutEmptyList" android:paddingBottom="32.0dip" android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ivHistoryPage"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/history_query_empty"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/history_query_empty"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/history_query_empty_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_history" />
        <TextView android:textSize="20.0sp" android:textColor="@color/blue_title"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tvHistoryPage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/SVEmptyHistoryTableMessage" android:lineSpacingExtra="2.0sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

DB.class

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
    private static final String COL1 = "ID";
    private static final String COL2 = "name";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL2 +" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean addData(String item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public Cursor getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getItemID(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    public void updateName(String newName, int id, String oldName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL2 +
                " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + oldName + "'";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
    public void deleteName(int id, String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this, just I have added this code in these lines and this is working like charm.

```
Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
           while (data.moveToNext()) {
               listData.add(data.getString(1));
           }
           if (data.getCount() != 0) {
           ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.history_item, R.id.historyName, listData);
           mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
       } else {
           mListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           noQueries.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
```